# MailMessage - Error Opening excel Attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
public void SendMail(string smtpAddress, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml,    string from, string to, string cc, string bcc,DataTable dt)
        {
           SmtpClient smtpClient = null;
        try
        {
            smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Host = smtpAddress;
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Byte[] contentAsBytes = SerializeData(dt);
                memoryStream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, "test.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");   
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

MailMessage generated but attached excel is giving error that the file you are trying to open is in a different format that specified by extension. verify that file is not corrupted and is trusted from a trusted source before opening file. On opening xsl it generates xsd format.
Kindly please help

Comment: How does SerializeData() method works, does it produce valid .xls file ?

Comment: This usually happens when you don't have the correct format. Is your data really an xls file.. Serialize data is probably returning tab separated file that is masquerading as xls. Its an old trick that I have used often, and excel just accepted back in the days.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion . Your suggestion works. Serialization method was not generating proper excel format